# ClassNotFoundException thrown after Data/Cache cleaning - second run OK

Tags: android

The application I am working on shows a strange symptom - if one cleans data and cache of the application, the application will crash on the first next run with exception, but on the second run it will run without a problem. Does anybody have any idea what could be going on and how to fix it.

What I already did:

1. deleted all the build dirs and rebuild
2. disabled instant run
3. check that the class is in the apk
4. tired it on multiple phones - all behave the same

Sadly nothing helped...

I am using the latest Android Studio 3.2.1. Compile and target SDK is 28, minimal 21. The app is written in Kotlin. Support lib is 28.0.0 and build tools 28.0.3.

The exception thrown on the first run (the name of the application was changed to protect the innocent):

```
2018-11-26 18:18:38.780 17135-17135/com.myapp.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.app, PID: 17135
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service service.ServerNotificationService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "service.ServerNotificationService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.app-YIEEjJIdfXs58PSDfpg4Ew==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.app-YIEEjJIdfXs58PSDfpg4Ew==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.myapp.app-YIEEjJIdfXs58PSDfpg4Ew==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3459)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1702)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "service.ServerNotificationService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.app-YIEEjJIdfXs58PSDfpg4Ew==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.app-YIEEjJIdfXs58PSDfpg4Ew==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.myapp.app-YIEEjJIdfXs58PSDfpg4Ew==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3456)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1702) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

Comment: May be your project contains **multidex** issue. Check if method limit exceeds 65k or not.

Comment: I have multiDexEnabled set to true and if it would be multidex problem it would not compile. Like I said the funniest thing is that this happens only after data/cache clean and only the first run. After that it is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix it. It was related to how Android tools merge *AndroidManifest.xml* files.

Let me explain (for posterity):

The application I am building is composed from a core - which is an android library and the actual application. The class *service.ServerNotificationService* is part of the library and was declared in *AndroidManifest.xml* of the said library as:

```
<service android:name="service.ServerNotificationService" />
```

Which is correct and the app will run - just not with the clean cache (I still do not understand this part, but I presume it has something to do with the black magic which is Android ART). To fix the problem I changed the line to:

```
<service android:name="com.myapp.app.core.service.ServerNotificationService" />
```

Which is the full name for the class. The lesson learned here is **always** use full class name in the libraries...